# usage of generic repository function

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I am new to EF Core. Below are my repository functions to Get:

```cs
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeString = null, bool disableTracking = true)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(includeString)) query = query.Include(includeString);

    if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

    if (orderBy != null)
        return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, List<Expression<Func<T, object>>> includes = null, bool disableTracking = true)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

    if (includes != null) query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));

    if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

    if (orderBy != null)
        return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

I know how to set filter condition. My question is: How do I call ***Include and OrderBy***?

Working example:

```cs
GetAsync(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(productName.ToLower()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need parameters for include. You can use this for include if you have relationships in database. It gets all tables (linked with your main table) automatically.

```
foreach (var property in _dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetNavigations())
    query = query.Include(property.Name);
```

like this.

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, bool disableTracking = true)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _dbContext.Set<T>();
        if (disableTracking) query = query.AsNoTracking();

        foreach (var property in _dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)).GetNavigations())
            query = query.Include(property.Name);

        if (predicate != null) query = query.Where(predicate);

        if (orderBy != null)
            return await orderBy(query).ToListAsync();
        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
```

### **Generic Repository**

[image]

**

### Controller

**
[image]

Comment: Thanks ...but I need to use get repository method

Comment: Yes, you can use it in get repository method. Edited post to make it clear. I removed includeString parameter.

Comment: Thanks . How i call this function in controller/service ?

Comment: Just call GetAsync(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(productName.ToLower())); as your usual. That's all. The code I have given get all included tables automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks ..it will load all related entities initially rite..it will effect in performance na..

Comment: i just want to know that how to call  GetAsync method from service layer & optionally send include in that..

Comment: It won't affect performance. I tested it. include 1 table = 5ms. include all tables = 0.5ms. About calling from service layer, if your GetAsync() is in "ItemService.cs" service layer, you can use this simple method in Controller => var serv = new ItemService(); var list = serv.GetAsync();. Google onion architecture to understand how to call function from service/repository layers.

Comment: i have added screenshots in my edited post. Get table without include and Get tables with all included tables almost same performance.